# watch -n1 $() does not run $() every interval

Tags: bash, echo, watch

`watch -n1 $()` does not update $().

what is the workaround?

here is my example:

```
watch -n1 echo $(( $(date +%s -d "sun") - $( date +%s ) ))
```

this results in

```
Every 1.0s: echo 106602                                                                                                                                                                                     

106602
```

the expected output should have been:

```
Every 1.0s: echo $(( $(date +%s -d "sun") - $( date +%s ) ))

106602
```

with `106602` being reduced every second

Comment: It likely *does* run every interval - but it's producing the same value each time because the arithmetic expression is evaluated before `watch` is invoked

Comment: how can I make it be evoked by watch instead of before it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It likely *does* run every interval - but it's overwriting the same value every time because the arithmetic expression is evaluated by your interactive shell before it is passed to the `watch` command. You can see this if you run `pgrep` from another terminal:

```
watch -n1 echo $(( $(date +%s -d "sun") - $( date +%s ) ))
```

then

```
$ pgrep -af watch
81 watchdogd
29311 watch -n1 echo 111748
```

You can prevent early evaluation by single-quoting the expression:

```
watch -n1 echo '$(( $(date +%s -d "sun") - $( date +%s ) ))'
```

giving

```
$ pgrep -af watch
81 watchdogd
29543 watch -n1 echo $(( $(date +%s -d "sun") - $( date +%s ) ))
```

which will pass the expression to a `/bin/sh` shell by default.

Comment: this fixes the problem.